# Xamarin: Problem with call on WebView <tel:...link

Tags: xamarin, xamarin.forms

Good evening,

I've been trying to solve the problem with clicking on <tel:....link in webview for a few days now.

I have tried several manuals but none of them work.
Can you please advise me?

Thank you

Comment: you haven't explained what the "problem" is or shown us your attempt to solve it

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use the `Webview.OnNavigating` event. Something like this should work:

Page.xaml.cs

```cs
private void WebView_OnNavigating(object sender, WebNavigatingEventArgs navigationEvent) {
    if (navigationEvent.Url.StartsWith("tel:")) {
         navigationEvent.Cancel = true;
         Xamarin.Essentials.Launcher.OpenAsync(navigationEvent.Url);
    }
}
```

Page.xaml

```xml
<WebView Navigating="WebView_OnNavigating" />
```